# Using GenServer from another application

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I'm struggling for a while now to use a GenServer in another application in my umbrella app.

Structure:
***apps:***

- project_a
- project_b

Project_a and project_b are both `--sup` applications and I want to use the GenServer from project_a in project_b. I've included the project in my deps.exs file, but I don't know what to do next...

If I open the observer I see both application in the menu, but I keep getting errors because project_b can't use project_a.

Does anyone know what I'm forgetting?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by “use”?

Comment: @mudasobwa I mean 'use' as in calling the methods

Comment: Do you have `apps_path: "apps"` in the umbrella’s project definition?

Comment: @mudasobwa yea I do, and in project_b I have `{:project_a, in_umbrella: true}` as dep

Comment: Just to make sure: you have referenced `project_a` app being a dependency of `project_b` in the `deps` section of `mix.exs`, haven’t you?

Comment: @mudasobwa I did, but I forgot to add in as application though. see my answer below.

Comment: Adding it to `applications` just autoloads it automatically, I was under an impression you have it loaded explicitly; anyway, good to know everything’s resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your answer to your own question is correct, I can tell you from experience that writing an adapter to your service in the other application is a good practice intended to more loosely couple the 2 applications together and to avoid circular references.

What do I mean by this?  Take the public API portion of the GenServer you are sending a message to and move it to another module in another application.  You will find this is very similar to writing a facade for an HTTP API.  The public API part of a GenServer is actually run from the calling process, even tough it is within the GenServer's module, so moving it to another module is just fine.

Please forgive any syntax problems etc in the following code as I am pulling it out of my head.

Change something like this:

```
defmodule App1.Calculator do
  use GenServer

  def add( num1, num2 ), do: GenServer.call( App1.Caclculator, {:add, num1, num2})

  def handle_call({:add, num1, num2}, _from, state) do
    {:reply, {:ok, num1+num2}, state}
  end
end
```

To:

```
defmodule App1.Calculator do
  use GenServer

  def handle_call({:add, num1, num2}, _from, state) do
    {:reply, {:ok, num1+num2}, state}
  end
end

defmodule Service.Calculator do
  def add(num1, num2), do: GenServer.call(process_name, {:add, num1, num2})

  # Just an example of how you might have named your node and calculator process
  def process_name, do: {:calculator, :"app1@127.0.0.1"}
end
```

Where `Service.Caclulator` is in a 3rd app named `Service` that can be depended on by `App1` and `App2` without creating a circular reference.

Why might you have to create a circular reference?  As soon as you are doing things asynchronously using `cast` from `App1` to `App2`, then `App2` will have to send a message with results to `App1`, and without the 3rd `Service` application, you would create a circular reference of `App1` and `App2`.  Not to mention when you start releasing two nodes (one for each app), there is no need to include the entirety of the other apps compiled code just to get an adapter to a service.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `project_a` in the `mix.exs` file from `project_b`.

It is not enough to add it as dep, but it must also be added in de `def application` part.

see: https://github.com/josevalim/kv_umbrella for an example.